# How can we check if every active ad group in an active campaign has an ad in Google Adwords?

Tags: google-ads

I am working on a very big PPC account. Is there an easy and fast way to QA the account to see if Every active ad group in an active campaign has an ad?

Answer (score 1):

[Adwords Editor](https://adwords.google.com/home/tools/adwords-editor/) has warnings like that. I can't remember if it has that specific check built in but if it doesn't then you can create a custom rule.

Comment: Thanks @Clayton Leis for the answer but am not able to download the accounts in Editor and it takes forever as they are pretty huge accounts. Is there any other way I can see that?

Comment: Not that I know of.